# Is encryption in-flight synonymous to encryption on/over-the-wire?

Tags: encryption

I hear both used interchangeably, but I figured over-the-wire implied some physical medium. Clarification would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think the terms "in transit" and "at rest" are superior as there is less ambiguity.